# How can I make pyplot.show() respect my font choice in matplotlibrc?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I have installed the Google font Lato on my system (Mac OS X) and if I set my matplotlibrc file to:

```
font.family         : sans-serif
font.sans-serif     : Lato, Bitstream Vera Sans, Lucida Grande, sans-serif
text.usetex         : False
```

I see my chosen font in figures produced as .png files with `plt.savefig('myfig.png')`. However, when I use `plt.show()`, I get the same old Bitstream Vera Sans font. How can I persuade matplotlib to use Lato in figures displayed with `show()`?

I'm using matplotlib 1.4.3 on Python 3.

Comment: Try removing your font cache. `import matplotlib.font_manager as mfm; print(mfm.get_cachedir())` to see where it is.

Comment: I did try this (I deleted the file called `fontList.py3k.cache` in `/Users/xnx/.matplotlib/`) but it hasn't helped, I'm afraid.

Comment: Can mpl find your font at all?  Try `fmf.findfont('Lato')`

Comment: Yup, `mfm.findfont('Lato')` returns `'/Users/xnx/Library/Fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf'`.